# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import - import * as gulp from 'gulp'

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

If you run gulp, you will get the following error message.

Is module required for gulpfile not installed? ..

```
$ gulp
[22:17:15] Failed to load external module ts-node/register
[22:17:15] Failed to load external module typescript-node/register
[22:17:15] Failed to load external module typescript-register
[22:17:15] Failed to load external module typescript-require
C:\project\interview\gulpfile.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as gulp f                                 rom 'gulp';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gu                                 lp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
```

Comment: use `--module commonjs` to target node including when running via `ts-node`

Comment: It looks as though you are using a `gulpfile.ts` dynamically compiled by _ts-node_. That's fine but you need to target NodeJS's module system, a derivative of CommonJS, via Typescript as noted or via another intermediate compiler to get that to work. You are outputting the `gulpfile` using `--module es2015`, probably via a co-located tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things you need to do to make gulp work with ES6 imports:

1. Rename `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.babel.js`
2. Run this command:

```
npm i @babel/preset-env @babel/register -D
```

3. Add a `.babelrc` file to the root folder of your project with the following code in it:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

You should now be able to use ES6 imports in your Gulp files.

Note: if you want to use TypeScript in your Gulp files instead, you should follow the steps outlined here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849088/1611058

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a ".babelrc" file in your Projekt folder (where also all your other config files are)

- Code (.babelrc)

  `{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }`

2) Setup/Install the Babel in your NPM (see https://babeljs.io/setup). E. g. with Node:

`npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev`

Comment: There are a few problems with your answer. In step 2 you say to install `babel-preset-env` but in step 1 you set `es2015` as the preset which is a different preset to what you told people to download. Lastly, you haven't mentioned that you need to add `.babel` to the gulp file.