# How can I run gulp with a typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, configuration, compilation, gulp

Have a gulp project that uses a gulp.js file but my project is in typescript so I'd rather have a gulp file in typescript. It would be possible to break the process into two steps where I:
 1. Manually transpile the typescript gulp file into js, then
 2. Call `gulp <some-task-name>`
But that doesn't seem optimal. Is there any better way of doing
    this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [Gulp docs for transpilation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4091bd3aff08801625c6128eec079af4a7b5dccb/docs/getting-started/2-javascript-and-gulpfiles.md#transpilation):

> ### Transpilation
>
> You can write a gulpfile using a language that requires transpilation, like TypeScript or Babel, by changing the extension on your `gulpfile.js` to indicate the language and install the matching transpiler module.
>
> - For TypeScript, rename to `gulpfile.ts` and install the [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) module.
> - For Babel, rename to `gulpfile.babel.js` and install the [@babel/register](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/register) module.

So the simpler way to add TypeScript support in Gulp:

1. Install [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), [`typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), and [@types/gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gulp):

   ```
   $ npm i -D ts-node typescript @types/gulp
   ```
2. If you have a `tsconfig.json` file set `ts-node.compilerOptions.module` to `"commonjs"`

   ```json
   {
       // these options are overrides used only by ts-node 
       "ts-node": {
           "compilerOptions": {
               "module": "commonjs" 
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   *(You don't need a `tsconfig.json` file, this is just for if you have one in your project already)*
3. Create `gulpfile.ts` with the following demo code:

   ```js
   import gulp from 'gulp'; // or import * as gulp from 'gulp'
   gulp.task('default', () => console.log('default'));
   ```

   *(or rename your existing `Gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.ts`)*
4. Start the build:

   ```
   $ npx gulp
   ```

The output should look similar to this:

```
$ gulp
[21:55:03] Requiring external module ts-node/register
[21:55:03] Using gulpfile ~/src/tmp/typescript-tmp/gulpfile.ts
[21:55:03] Starting 'default'...
default
[21:55:03] Finished 'default' after 122 μs
```

Comment: This does not work anymore. I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` if the project's `type` is `commonjs` and `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"` if the project's type is `module`

Comment: I've posted an issue in Gulp to see if this method can start working again. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2623

Comment: I've investigated the issue a bit more. I had 2 projects, both with bare minimum node_modules. One was failing with the error mentioned, the other worked perfectly. The difference was that the one that worked perfectly had no tsconfig.json file. So something in the tsconfig file is causing the error. Secondly, this is an issue with ts-node, not Gulp.

Comment: This gave the answer I was looking for :)  https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922#issuecomment-667076602 It says that the `"module"` field under `"compilerOptions"` needs to be set to `"commonjs"`. I've updated the answer to include the required tsconfig.json setting

Comment: I've edited the answer again to incorporate the advice given in this comment (lets you still use ts in Gulp even in a Vite project that needs to be able to use ESM style modules) https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922#issuecomment-673155000

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs into this, @tony19's answer above will only work for some projects ;-)

`import * as gulp from 'gulp';` won't always work (it depends on your tsconfig.json settings- specifically `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`), the "safer" thing to use is `import gulp from 'gulp';` which should work regardless of the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` value.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `gulp.js` file in the root of your project with nothing but the following line.

`eval(require('typescript').transpile(require('fs').readFileSync("./gulp.ts").toString()));`

Then create another actual gulp file written in typescript in a file `gulp.ts`. What will happen is that the `gulp.js` file will be loaded but will bootstrap the process by compiling your `gulp.ts' file and passing the transpiled results instead.

This allows us to not have to precompile the gulp.ts file before using it. Instead you can just type `gulp test` and it will be executed from your tyepscript file without any extra calls.

- Make sure to run the following first:
  `npm install typescript --save-dev`
  `npm install fs --save-dev`

Comment: This sounds promising but you're missing a lot of steps in the instructions. Gulp needs a `gulpfile.js` or you get a `No gulpfile found` error. If I put your code snippet in a `gulpfile.js` I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'task' of undefined`. Same if I paste the code snippet inside a default gulp task. You also don't provide the code snippet for your `gulp test` command.