# Is it possible to have TS Vite use ESM and have TS Gulp use Common JS in the same project?

Tags: typescript, gulp, commonjs, vite, es6-modules

This is my specific scenario:

1. I have a [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) project that uses TypeScript
2. I am adding [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to it to handle some automation tasks
3. I want Gulp files to be written in TypeScript so I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847926/how-can-i-run-gulp-with-a-typescript-file/49849088#49849088)
4. I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2623)

The creator of Gulp responded with this:

> You are using esm, so this is a duplicate of [gulpjs/rechoir#43](https://github.com/gulpjs/rechoir/issues/43)... You can switch back to CJS.

What I want to know is if it is possible for TypeScript Gulp (so a `gulpfile.ts` file) to run on Common JS while Vite can still run on ESM and use TypeScript files.

Answer (score 1):

This question was able to answered by this other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849088/1611058

(Note it was updated with the answer I needed after posting this question)

Apply this to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    // these options are overrides used only by ts-node 
    "ts-node": {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "commonjs" 
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow ts-node to compile your gulp files using CommonJS and let Vite compile the rest of your code using ESM.